Can't find table position in image with opencv
I want to process tabular data from images. To do this, we read the image with opencv and find where the table is by going through the following seven steps. In image number 7, we plan to crop based on the border. In the following example data, it works exactly what I want. This is because there is a black outer border of the image internal table.
image = cv2.imread(image_path, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)


grayscaled_image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)


_, thresholded_image = cv2.threshold(grayscaled_image, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)


inverted_image = cv2.bitwise_not(thresholded_image)


dilated_image = cv2.dilate(inverted_image, None, iterations=3)


contours, _ = cv2.findContours(dilated_image, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
image_with_all_contours = image.copy()
cv2.drawContours(image_with_all_contours, contours, -1, (0, 255, 0), 2)


rectangular_contours = []
for contour in contours:
    peri = cv2.arcLength(contour, True)
    epsilon = peri * 0.02
    approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(contour, epsilon, True)
    if len(approx) == 4:
        rectangular_contours.append(approx)
image_with_only_rectangular_contours = image.copy()
cv2.drawContours(image_with_only_rectangular_contours, rectangular_contours, -1, (0, 255, 0), 2)


max_area = 0
max_area_contour = None
for contour in rectangular_contours:
    area = cv2.contourArea(contour)
    if area > max_area:
        max_area = area
        max_area_contour = contour

image_with_max_area_contour = image.copy()
cv2.drawContours(image_with_max_area_contour, [max_area_contour], -1, (0, 255, 0), 2)


However, there are cases where the table does not have an outer border, as shown in the following picture. In reality, the image I want to work with does not have lines on the outside. The image below is a temporary work created for explanation purposes.
As you can see in the picture above, if there is no outer border, problems arise in the process of obtaining the Thresholded Image. Later, it becomes impossible to leave a square contour line by doing cv2.findContours.
Ultimately, what I want is to read the values in the Name and Favorite columns into Pandas. I am currently following the process by referring to this post. How can I select the rectangle of the largest contour line?



TRYING 1 by @Ivan
The following image is when cv2.RETE_EXTERNAL is applied when doing cv2.findContours. The cotour line is drawn as follows. That is, the outermost part is not drawn.

TRYING 2 by @cards
If you select 50*30 instead of the default kernel size, a distorted rectangle is selected as shown below.
dilated_image = cv2.dilate(inverted_image, np.ones((50, 30), np.uint8), iterations=1)




i think you forgot the last image

cv2.findContours has an option RETR_EXTERNAL where it's easy to get the most outern contour

you can do a dilation with an "ultra" big kernel (maybe only vertical or horizontal or even both) and then use findContours with the proper options as already suggested

@Ivan I added the missing photos as you mentioned and applied RETR_EXTERNAL. Unfortunately, it doesn't work as well as the edited post.

@cards I understand it as the basic kernel 33. If you change this to something large, like 5030, you will end up with a distorted rectangle that is selected that is not accurate.

once you have the minimal rectangle get its boundingRect(cnt)

after getting the contours , make a loop over all of them comparing contourArea to get the biggest, then apply boundingRect to it

Rather than converting to grayscale and thresholding, use cv2.inRange() on the input color image with ranges to find the yellow background color.

Have a look at the Red channel of your image. That yellow color has a Red component of 255. Everything else is <255. Once you get rid of the dark lines on the border of the image, you have a perfect mask.

I'm not sure how general your example is, depending on this my answer might change.
To start:
%matplotlib notebook
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
im = cv2.imread("table.jpg") # read im
b, g, r = cv2.split(im) # split to bgr
imRGB = cv2.merge([r,g,b]) # generate rgb image for plotting...

As a summary, it's always good to look at the different colours that make up an image. Here's how your image looks like in their RGB channels:
fig, axs = plt.subplots(nrows = 1, ncols = 3, sharex = True, sharey = True)
axs[0].imshow(r)
axs[1].imshow(g)
axs[2].imshow(b)
plt.suptitle("R|G|B")
plt.tight_layout()
for ax in axs:
    ax.axis("off")

We see from this that the R channel offers the most contrast between the table and the background.

So, thresholding there would make sense:
mask = (r<240).astype(np.uint8)
plt.figure()
plt.imshow(mask)
plt.axis("off")

We see here that indeed the threshold works nicely:

We can do a small closing operation and then find contours and draw contours on the image:
mask = (r<240).astype(np.uint8)
maskClosed = cv2.morphologyEx(mask, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, np.ones((5,5)))
contours = cv2.findContours(maskClosed, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)[0]
largestContour = max(contours, key=cv2.contourArea)
imRGB = cv2.drawContours(imRGB, [largestContour], 0, (255,0,0), 5)
plt.figure()
plt.imshow(imRGB)
plt.axis("off")

We get the following:

Already quite good, we can use this with cv2.boundingRect(largestContour) to get the coordinates for cropping: (104, 68, 389, 137)
Let me know if this works for you or not..

This codes makes a mask image (similar as your last detection) and gets the over all bounding rectangle:
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Create a completely black mask image
mask = np.zeros((300, 400), dtype=np.uint8)

# Draw white rectangles
cv2.rectangle(mask, (140, 50), (150, 250), (255), thickness=cv2.FILLED)
cv2.rectangle(mask, (50, 100), (350, 150), (255), thickness=cv2.FILLED)

# Find contours
contours, _ = cv2.findContours(mask, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

# Get bounding rectangles of contours
bounding_rects = [cv2.boundingRect(cnt) for cnt in contours]

# Find the overall bounding rectangle
x, y, w, h = bounding_rects[0]
max_x = x + w
max_y = y + h
for rect in bounding_rects[1:]:
    x = min(x, rect[0])
    y = min(y, rect[1])
    max_x = max(max_x, rect[0] + rect[2])
    max_y = max(max_y, rect[1] + rect[3])
    w = max_x - x
    h = max_y - y

print(x, y, w, h)

# Draw the overall bounding rectangle
cv2.rectangle(mask, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (255), 2)

# Save the mask image
cv2.imwrite('mask.png', mask)

# Draw the overall rectangle on a copy of the mask
mask_with_rectangle = mask.copy()
# Draw in gray
cv2.rectangle(mask_with_rectangle, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (50), 2)

# Save the image with the overall rectangle
cv2.imwrite('mask_with_rectangle.png', mask_with_rectangle)


You can replace mask by your dilated_image
